# Prove for Lp norm

Tags: real-analysis

If

$$f_n = n I\left[\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n}\right],$$

show that the $L_p$ norm of $f_n$ is 1.

I am using the definition of $L_p$ norm which is $\left(\int |X|^p dP\right)^{1/p}$. In this case it would be $$\left(\int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{2}{n}} n^p dx\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} = \left(\frac{n^p}{n}\right)^\frac{1}{p} \ne 1.$$
I am not sure where I am making the mistake. Can any one correct it?

Comment: Who told you that the $L_p$ norm is $1$?  It is actually $n^{1-1/p}$.  You did make a mistake where you have $(n^p/n)^p$ instead of $(n^p/n)^{1/p}$.

Answer (score 2):

The $L_p$ norm is not $1$.  The only mistake in the computation, perhaps a typo, was fixed in Cameron's edit.

Answer (score 1):

In general The $L_p$ norm is not $1$, but I think it's worth mentioning that if $p=1$ then it IS equal to 1, since:

$$\left(\int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{2}{n}} n^p dx\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}= \left(\int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{2}{n}} n^1 dx\right)^1 = \frac{n}{n} = 1.$$